# PHP MYSQL, 1292: Incorrect date value: '' for column 'sale_date' at row 1

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL database with a clients table and a person(used for testing) table. My HTML, PHP, and scripts work as expected in the person table. When using the same coding in my clients table I get the following error "1292: Incorrect date value: '' for column 'sale_date' at row 1.

My HTML code is as follows:

```
<label>Sale Date:&nbsp <input id="cSaleDate" class="cSale" type="date" name="cSaleDate"></label>
```

My PHP code:

```
$sale_date = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['cSaleDate']);

if (isset($_POST['cSaleDate']))
    {
        include_once('client.php');
        $saleDate = date('0000-00-00', strtotime($sale_date));
        if (!empty($_POST['cSaleDate']))
        {
            $saleDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($sale_date));
        }
    }

$fields = 'fips_code, size_code, client_name, client_state, sale_date';
$values = "'$fips_code', '$size_code', '$client_name', '$client_state', '$saleDate'";

$sql = "INSERT INTO clients ($fields) VALUES ($values)";
```

The column for the sale date is set as:

```
Name: sale_date
Datatype: DATE
Default: NULL
```

As mentioned before, this code does work with dates in the "person" table, but not with the "clients" table. I have the date column setup the same on both tables. Any help or ideas on why this works for one table but not the other would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "$saleDate = date('0000-00-00', strtotime($sale_date));" - you might start by cleaning up your code. It would also have been helpful to know what values you were posting and what the resultant SQL looked like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for the help. I ended up using a ternary statement in the insert, which allowed me to insert 'NULL' into the date field in the database if the input is left blank.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (SaleDate) VALUES (" . ($saleDate == '' ? 'NULL' : "'$saleDate'") . ")"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code largely depends on `$_POST['cSaleDate']` and from the snippet you've provided if you don't actually get that value then `$saleDate` would be undefined. That is my best guess at what the problem may be.

Here is a possible way to rewrite that snippet:

```
// It seems you want this as your default if there is no $_POST['cSaleDate']?
$saleDate = '0000-00-00';

// Now check if you should overwrite this default
if (isset($_POST['cSaleDate'])) {
    include_once('client.php');
    if ( ! empty($_POST['cSaleDate'])) {
        $saleDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['cSaleDate']));
    }
}

// Now do your escape and db insert
$saleDate = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $saleDate);

$fields = 'fips_code, size_code, client_name, client_state, sale_date';
$values = "'$fips_code', '$size_code', '$client_name', '$client_state', '$saleDate'";

$sql = "INSERT INTO clients ($fields) VALUES ($values)";
```

Comment: It is dangerous to recommend 0000-00-00 as default date value because depending on MySQL configuration, this value may generate an invalid date value error. If no date is set, then use null.

Comment: The OP had it in their code so I left it as is but I would agree with your recommendation.

Comment: Unfortunately, when the type=date input is left blank I get an invalid date format error. That's why I am using  $saleDate = date('0000-00-00', strtotime($sale_date));. I cannot get it to accept a blank date.